# relative_time expression meaning

Tags: splunk, splunk-query

I have a set of data with timestamps: eg, 12.50pm, 1pm, 1.30pm, 1.50pm, 2pm, 2.20pm, 3pm, 3.30pm

At the start of the code, I have split them into timespan: ie

> bucket _time span = 1h

I have been trying to understand this expression so that I can determine which sign to use in the where clause later, :

> relative_time(max(_time),"@h")

What do they mean and how do they differ?

```
|where _time < relative_time(max(_time),"@h")
|where _time = relative_time(max(_time),"@h")
|where _time > relative_time(max(_time),"@h")
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's pull the expression apart.

`max(_time)` is the same as `_time` because the `where` command only looks at a single event, which has only one _time field.

`relative_time(max(_time),"@h")` takes the epoch timestamp in the first argument and "rounds off" based on the second argument.  In this case, _time is rounded off to the start of the current hour.

The `where` command selects the current event if it meets the specified criteria (IOW, the expression is true); otherwise, the event is discarded.

`|where _time < relative_time(max(_time),"@h")` - chooses the event if it occurred before the start of the hour

`|where _time = relative_time(max(_time),"@h")` - chooses the event if it occurred at the top of the hour

`|where _time > relative_time(max(_time),"@h")` - chooses the event if it occurred after the start of the hour

Comment: Thanks! But I do not understand your first sentence; shouldnt max(_time) be just 3pm and stays consistently throughout? How is it the same as _time? Assuming I have the following eventstats statement before the where statements, does the above explanation still stand?
|eventstats max(_time) as mtime 
|where _time < relative_time(mtime,"@h")
|where _time = relative_time(mtime,"@h")
|where _time > relative_time(mtime,"@h")